# How same variable is used for ng-bind and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am exploring AngularJS1 and found something strange, please help me to find how `name` is working for both ng-bind and ng-model here.

Output is coming as :**John Doe** but it is working for same variable name with bind and model there it is confusing me.Please help me to understand.

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input ng-model="name">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1><br>
    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
    </div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
});
</script>
```

Comment: what's the confusion ?

Comment: How it is allowing same variable for bind and model?, what is the mechanism behind this? thanks for reply.

Comment: {{}} & ng-bind are used to display the data in UI, you declared $scope.name in the controller is same for both. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all the same variable. You have `$scope.name` and you're telling `ng-bind` and `ng-model` to use `$scope.name`;

`ng-model="name"` <-- Angular looks on the scope object for a property called name. If it's there it uses it, if it's not, it'll create it.

`ng-bind="name"`  <-- Angular looks on the scope for a property called name. Then uses that value.

Angular created a scope object for the div with `ng-controller`

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input ng-model="name">
    <h1>{{name}}</h1><br>
    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</div>
```

All directives with-in that div's hierarchy can access the scope object. 
If you Google "Understanding Angular scopes" or something similar you'll get a lot of articles on it.

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/11/angularjs-scopes-an-introduction/

Comment: @Jerinam Thanks for your answer.